# Xamarin forms picker item source not loading

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker

I have created a list of stores added it to a picker but from the views it is not loading. It is showing a picker with no items.

ViewModel code as follows

```
public List<string> Stores = new List<string>
        {
            "store 1",
            "store 2",
            "store 3"
        };

private int _selectedStoreIndex = -1;
        public int SelectedStoreIndex
        {
            get { return _selectedStoreIndex; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedStoreIndex != value)
                {
                    _selectedStoreIndex = value;

                    UpdateStoreSelection();
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
```

Xaml file

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Stores}" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedStoreIndex}"/>
```

Comment: Hi, you could have a look at [Lifecycle methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle#lifecycle-methods) to add timer inside `OnStart/OnSleep/OnResume` to calculate the running time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue with Updating the Data from ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

When a cold start is made `OnStart` method in `App.xaml.cs` is called. You can then use [Secure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage) / [Preference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/preferences) to save a key in local storage in each platform and then just use DateTime.Now to just calculate the difference. And when the app is destroyed and restarted , `OnStart` will be called again and just reset the key.

Answer (score 0):

You just need get the start time of the process,and the current time.

```
var startime = Process.GetCurrentProcess().StartTime;
var currenttime = DateTime.Now;
var runningtime = (nowtime - startime).TotalSeconds;
```